# ATTINY85 pin doesn't go fully LOW when in PWM

Tags: avr, pwm

I have connected 3 LEDs to ATTINY85 (PWM mode). Each LED is connected with NPN3904 and 68 ohm resistor to the PB0, PB1 or PB5 port.

Everything works great, except for some reason when I set the *OCR0A* or *OCR0B* values to 0, nether will go fully LOW, but instead will continue to give out a weak signal, while setting *OCR1B* to 0 works as expected and PB5 goes fully LOW:

[image]

Code:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void main()
{
    DDRB   = 1 << DDB4   | 1 << DDB1   | 1 << DDB0;
    TCCR0A = 2 << COM0A0 | 2 << COM0B0 | 3 << WGM00;
    TCCR0B = 0 << WGM02  | 1 << CS00;
    TCCR1  = 0 << PWM1A  | 0 << COM1A0 | 1 << CS10;
    GTCCR  = 1 << PWM1B  | 2 << COM1B0;

    for (;;)
    {
        OCR0A = 0x00;
        OCR0B = 0x00;
        OCR1B = 0x00;

        _delay_ms( 1000 );

        OCR0A = 0xFF;
        OCR0B = 0xFF;
        OCR1B = 0xFF;

        _delay_ms( 1000 );
    }
}
```

I have rotated all the components and tested with VCC in the range from 2.7v to 3.5v but still the same result occurs. The issue seems to be tied to the PB0 and PB1 pins specifically. Any hints on what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a schematic and proper voltage (best scope) measurements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) of this mcu is this behaviour explained and also hints at how to change it.

> If
>    the OCR0A is set equal to BOTTOM, the output will be a narrow spike for each MAX+1 timer clock cycle. Setting the OCR0A equal to MAX will result in a constantly high or
>    low output (depending on the
>   polarity of the output se
>   t by the COM0A[1:0] bits.)

Meaning that they cant reach 0% PWM, but they can reach 100%. For your aplication you can then invert outputs and invert meaning in code.

```
OCR0A = 0x00; //fully on
OCR0A = 0xFF; //fully off
```

This will turn off LED completely.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the salient part of the datasheet.  Your answer is *almost* right, but the problematic "special case" is also inverted.  Basically **you CAN have true 0% duty cycle in inverting PWM mode, but conversely you CANNOT have 100% in inverting PWM mode**.  Given that most people will be using PWM to generate DAC style signals, nobody is likely to notice that maximum is actually only 99.9999 % D.C.  Interestingly, at 1Mhz frequency, non-inverting PWM on an ATTiny85 WILL visibly light up an LED when `OCR0A = 0x00;` is used.  Funny thing, but that's how I ended up replying to this :)

Answer (score 1):

Most pwm generators cannot go 0% dc or 100% dc correctly: they will be 1 tick high or 1 tick low, giving you what you saw.

two ways to do it.

1) if the pwm generator allows inversion, set the dc to the other extreme. LM3S would be in this category;

2) or to exit pwm at 0% or 100% dc and set the pin low or high. arduino takes this approach.